# What does importing Foundation do to String?

Tags: swift, foundation

When I import Foundation, all of a sudden `String` objects (among others) are able to do a bunch of things they didn’t before. How does this feature work? Are there any downsides to it? Will it change the behavior of code I wrote before adding the import?

Answer (score 2):

The `NSString` class from Foundation is [bridged](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/WorkingWithCocoaDataTypes.html) to Swift's `String`, so its methods appear as [extensions on the built-in String type](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/becc22ff3183f980dde113409929920ca1925038/apinotes/Foundation.apinotes#L102-L104).

When you call one of the NSString methods, the object is [magically bridged to Objective-C](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/781ee82cf676e6121c0dd935c0f69ef43f627721/stdlib/public/SDK/Foundation/String.swift#L31-L36) where it becomes a [subclass of NSString](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/c3b7709a7c4789f1ad7249d357f69509fb8be731/stdlib/public/core/StringBridge.swift#L208).

Comment: this doesn’t really answer my question…I know that Foundation changes `String` but the question is *how* it changes it. Is the entire `String` type now a different data type? What happened to the native Swift `String`s? Or does Swift convert the strings to an `NSString` and then back to its original form whenever I call a Foundation method on it?

Comment: It's not replaced, it just has new methods and bridging support.

Comment: so what exactly happens to the string when I call a foundation method on it?

Comment: It is [bridged on the fly](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/c3b7709a7c4789f1ad7249d357f69509fb8be731/stdlib/public/core/StringBridge.swift#L315-L322) to a subclass of NSString called [`_NSContiguousString`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/c3b7709a7c4789f1ad7249d357f69509fb8be731/stdlib/public/core/StringBridge.swift#L208).

Comment: does it get converted back when the method returns?

Comment: Yes, when you receive an NSString back as a String, the String can simply be a [lightweight wrapper](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/c3b7709a7c4789f1ad7249d357f69509fb8be731/stdlib/public/core/StringBridge.swift#L60).

Comment: i’m even more confused as to what is going on sorry…